# Put stretched rows inside a column in flutter app

Tags: android-layout, flutter, dart

I am building a flutter app layout which requires to have some widgets to be put horizontally together in a row ,
some Rows should be put together in a column,

i tried to put the rows inside the column directly but it didn't work,
that's the code used:

```
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center ,

            children: <Widget>[

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: new Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      //the problem shows up here
 ],
                  ),

                ),
              ),

              //card to hold the addition form
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: new Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child:new Card(
                  color:Colors.white,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),
                  child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
         ...

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                    new BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      blurRadius: 2.0,
                      offset: new Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

update:
that's exactly what i want to make
a main column that contain rows and columns to build this view 
putting the card inside the column is working fine but nothing work when i add row inside the column 
i also updated the code and hope it's completely clear now
[image]

Comment: i tried to understand your question many times but i fail :'D

Comment: I didn't understand correctly also, as @MohamedGaber!!, but I noticed that the Text widgets in second column are WHITE colored, so I changed them to black and they were appeared. I hope with all my heart to not be this the problem you have !

Comment: Everything is working well just change background color of card because both background and text color are white so it's not showing.
new Card(
                          color:Colors.white,//chage here
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),

Comment: sorry i couldn't make it so clear :'D
may you see the updates

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the alignment
this worked fine
'''
child: new SingleChildScrollView(
        // the main content container
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: new Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0, top: 20.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 0.0),

```
            //Current date and time container
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        //card to hold the addition form
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
          child: new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

            //the addition shadow handler
            child: new Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)),

              //the addition form container
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Type and amount container
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        //Amount container
                        new Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[

                          ],
                        ),

                        //Type container
                        new Column(
                          children: <Widget>[

                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
              new BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                blurRadius: 2.0,
                offset: new Offset(0.0, 0.0),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

'''